# how to find specific text in files using grep in shell

Tags: shell, grep, find

I want to search for some string is all subfolders directly in files

I need to find out string:

```
DEBUG ('[S:B:H] project=', $project->name, '<<<<<<<<<<<<<');
```

I used to use grep -lir 'some text' *

but I suppose it isn't working like that.

Comment: You have to escape any special characters that appear in the text. Alternatively try the `-F` flag and wrap the string in `"`

Answer (score 1):

this one works ::

```
grep -lier 'DEBUG ('\''\[S:B:H] project='\'', $project->name, '\''<<<<<<<<<<<<<'\'');' <testfile>
```